# Writing/Reading a struct from a .txt file

Tags: c, struct, file-io

I'm trying to write an array of structs to a file, then read that file into an empty array of structs and print out the variables within each struct element of the array.

my code is below, currently I just have it to try to print the first element, but nothing is printed out to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[1024];
    int price;
} game;

void main(){
    FILE *filename;
    filename = fopen("file.txt","w");

    game library[3]; //creation of our game library
    //initializing the array to be written, 3 structs inside this array should be written to the file in sizeof(game).
    strcpy(library[0].name,"Minecraft");
    strcpy(library[1].name,"Opium");
    strcpy(library[2].name,"Devil");
    library[0].price = 10;
    library[1].price = 20;
    library[2].price = 30;

    fwrite(library,sizeof(game),3,filename);
    fseek(filename,0,SEEK_SET);

    game second[3];
    printf("test");
    fread(second,sizeof(game),3,filename);
    printf("element 0 is %s $%d",second[0].name,second[0].price);
    fclose(filename);
}
```

Comment: you are opening the file in the "w" mode. You need to open in the "w+" mode to allow reading and writing.

Comment: ah easy mistake, my code works now thanks! @RishikeshRaje